# Gdb function entry point not known

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I am using a vendor API whose sources I have, I can set breakpoints and they hit well, but if I try to call a function ( by its name ) in gdb, it says "Entry point address is not known.", what does it mean and is there any workaround ? I tried googling, but dont find anything useful. Thanks a lot for any help. Next step I am thinking to get the address of the function using objdump and then try calling with address directly, if it works. But I dont know exactly how to do that, please guide me here as well, the vendor library is dynamically linked with my own program

EDIT 1: 
After doing "info address "function"", I tried to call like "call (*"address")(params)", still it shows the same error, note that it does know about the functions address.

Comment: Did you build the vendor library with debugging symbols (ie, `-g` flag for gcc or clang)?

Comment: @CarlNorum Would the breakpoints hit if the library didn't have debugging symbols?

Comment: Probably, yes.  The function names aren't the only thing included with debugging information, and often are included even without.

Comment: But I can hit breakpoints if I say-- b "fun", and I can see the sources, doesnt that mean that it has debugging symbols ?

Comment: @avd - I'd think so, yeah.  Sorry, I think I was misunderstanding your question. You want to call the function directly from the gdb command line?

Comment: @carl: yes, I want to call from gdb prompt, after I hit some breakpoint: "call function", note that if I hit breakpoint for the same function and if its called from my program source, I do hit that breakpoint.

Comment: Is it dynamically linked?  Has the library been loaded by the time you try to execute that `call` command?

Comment: Yes the library is loaded, since I said, if I put a breakpoint on the same function, I do hit that, the only problem is I cant call on my own.

Comment: Sorry - it wasn't clear to me if you had tried the `call` both before and after hitting that breakpoint.

Comment: yes, I tried after hitting the breakpoint as well, it still shows the same error about entry point.

Comment: Try 'print' instead of 'call'. Does it help?

Comment: @n.m.I did not understand, I want to call inside that function.

Comment: Maybe the function is inline, or in reality a macro? Or lives in a plugin that is loaded dynamically?

Comment: Neither is the function inline nor a macro, as I said, if I put a breakpoint like "b function", I do hit that breakpoint, and bt shows that frame in the backtrace, the only thing is I am not able to call on that function directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an obscure one!

When making an inferior call, gdb has a few options for where to put the dummy stack frame it creates.  In your case it is choosing the "entry point" -- basically (I think) the memory at _start, which is executed once and then never used again.  This choice seem to be architecture-specific.

In your case, gdb can't find the entry point.  This can happen if you never used the "file" command, or if you are debugging a .o file and not a real executable, but it seems it can happen in some other, more obscure, scenarios as well.

Comment: This happened to me when using gdb-multiarch to debug an Android application on an ARM device. @Tom Tromey, do you know of any workaround?

Comment: Found out what a workaround to my problem: I was trying to run a stripped .so in the ARM device and set gdb to look for the unstripped .so in the x86 machine. When I deployed the stripped version I was able to call functions from gdb.